# PowerShell MDB Query - Script Works in Access not in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, ms-access

As subject says I have a working query on the MDB directly in Access, I have a PowerShell script that works with a different query, but this query returns no data.  Ideas?

This works...

```
$path = "C:\temp\Config.mdb"
$adOpenStatic = 3
$adLockOptimistic = 3
$cn = new-object -comobject ADODB.Connection
$rs = new-object -comobject ADODB.Recordset

$cn.Open("Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source = $path")
$Ports = $rs.open("Select * from Options where OptionName='Eng.SerialPortMgr.PrinterPort1'",$cn,$adOpenStatic,$adLockOptimistic)
$rs.MoveFirst()

do {
$rs.Fields.Item("OptionName").value + " = " + $rs.Fields.Item("OptionData").value; 
$rs.MoveNext()} 
until($rs.EOF -eq $True)

$rs.Close()
$cn.Close()

$Ports
```

This does not and I do not see why.  The only difference is the query and the query in this script bellow works in Access...

```
$path = "C:\temp\Config.mdb"
$adOpenStatic = 3
$adLockOptimistic = 3
$cn = new-object -comobject ADODB.Connection
$rs = new-object -comobject ADODB.Recordset

$cn.Open("Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source = $path")
$Ports = $rs.open("SELECT Options.OptionName, Options.OptionData FROM Options WHERE OptionName LIKE 'Eng.SerialPortMgr.PrinterPort*'",$cn,$adOpenStatic,$adLockOptimistic)
$rs.MoveFirst()

do {
$rs.Fields.Item("OptionName").value + " = " + $rs.Fields.Item("OptionData").value; 
$rs.MoveNext()} 
until($rs.EOF -eq $True)

$rs.Close()
$cn.Close()

$Ports
```

Comment: `%` is the wildcard character in SQL. Not `*`.

Comment: Tried both neither produce results

Comment: since you are only selecting from one table, I would also try removing the table identifiers from your SELECT clause.

Comment: What does $rs.Count give you?

Comment: so i tinkered with it and got it working, the % is what it likes in the script.  Not sure why it didnt work before i must have fixed a typo or something i wasnt seeing.  Its all part of a large WPF shell script i probably tripped myself up lol.

Answer (score 0):

This worked...

```
$path = "C:\temp\Config.mdb"
$adOpenStatic = 3
$adLockOptimistic = 3
$cn = new-object -comobject ADODB.Connection
$rs = new-object -comobject ADODB.Recordset

$cn.Open("Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source = $path")
$SawConfigPorts = $rs.open("SELECT Options.OptionName, Options.OptionData FROM Options WHERE OptionName LIKE 'Eng.SerialPortMgr.PrinterPort%'",$cn,$adOpenStatic,$adLockOptimistic)
$rs.MoveFirst()

do {
    $rs.Fields.Item("OptionName").value + " = " + $rs.Fields.Item("OptionData").value; 
        $rs.MoveNext() } 
        until($rs.EOF -eq $True)

$rs.Close()
$cn.Close()

$SawConfigPorts
```

Comment: This answer would be better if you included what you changed so future readers don't have to manually compare your code blocks to see what is different.